# "Error: Too many binds" when executing an INSERT command on SqlBase

Tags: guptateamdeveloper, sqlbase

I need help with this error on SqlBase, i've never seen it before.

**This are the table columns:**

```
NAME                       COLNO COLTYPE       LENGTH       SCALE NULLS UPDATES
==================================== =========== ======== =========== =========== ===== =======
COD_CADENA                     1 INTEGER        4       0 N Y
COD_FARMACIA                   2 INTEGER        4       0 N Y
NRO_MOVIMIENTO                 3 INTEGER        4       0 N Y
DATO1                          4 VARCHAR       20       0 Y Y
DATO2                          5 VARCHAR       20       0 Y Y
DATO3                          6 VARCHAR       20       0 Y Y
DATO4                          7 VARCHAR       20       0 Y Y
DATO5                          8 VARCHAR       20       0 Y Y
DATO6                          9 VARCHAR       20       0 Y Y
DATO7                         10 VARCHAR       20       0 Y Y
DATO8                         11 VARCHAR       20       0 Y Y
DATO9                         12 VARCHAR       40       0 Y Y
DATO10                        13 VARCHAR       40       0 Y Y
ESTADO                        14 INTEGER        4       0 Y Y
STRING1                       15 VARCHAR      200       0 Y Y
DOCUMENTO                     16 VARCHAR       30       0 Y Y
NRO_DOCUMENTO                 17 VARCHAR       30       0 Y Y
URL                           18 VARCHAR      250       0 Y Y
USA_TRACK                     19 INTEGER        4       0 Y Y
SYNC_INFO_FLAG                20 INTEGER        4       0 Y Y
```

**Primary keys:**
COD_CADENA,
COD_FARMACIA,
NRO_MOVIMIENTO

**This is the INSERT command:**

```
INSERT INTO MOV_VALIDADORA (
ESTADO,
USA_TRACK,
DATO1,
DATO10,
DATO2,
DATO3,
DATO4,
DATO5,
DATO6,
DATO7,
DATO8,
DATO9,
DOCUMENTO,
NRO_DOCUMENTO,
STRING1,
URL,
COD_CADENA,
COD_FARMACIA,
NRO_MOVIMIENTO) 
values (
null,
0.00000,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
'DNI',
'1212121212',
NULL,
NULL,
1.00000,
716.00000,
5435863.00000);
```

**When executing this command i get this error, what does it mean?, i dont see anything wrong in the command**

```
Error: 00113 SQL TMB Application Programming Error: Too many binds
```

Thank you!

PS: Why stackoverflow asks me to add more text? my question is already crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Remove decimal point and all the zeros behind (maybe it's a problem with number-literal and regional settings)
2. To narrow the problem first only insert the values for the 3 NOT NULL values. Then step by step add the other column-values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have any binds.   Try removing one column and its corresponding value  from the Insert statement one at a time until the Insert works.
Assume you're using SQLTalk here, and not some third party hack that uses a router.

Comment: Hey Steve, Yes i'm using SqlTalk i narrowed that to the point that i only used those 3 primary keys, and the result is the same. I have a trigger i that table may the error come from an action there?

Comment: Try to disalbe the trigger.

Comment: If you need to disable the Trigger or capture the script used to create it ( so you can drop and recreate it ) - then use the SQLBase Command Center - it so much easier than SQLTalk for that sort of thing.   Its 'sbccntr.exe' in your server side SQLBase folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the values to Variables and insert the Variables instead of hardcoded Values. That also prevents you from SQLInjection.